# C++ waiting for process to finish multiple times?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, unix, waitpid

Help me correct my confusion, I have a job running in bg with pid = 3

I want to check if it has finished every 10 sec (non blocking) and print hello once and stop;

But someone claimed the following:

1. this won't work as status can be consumed **only once**.
2. Even if you stopped after first run, your check isn't right. you should check returned pid_t value **and status too.**

and he added:

> just remember that waitpid is waiting for state change, and if a
> previous call has already consumed this change, the second call will
> block for other changes

I am just confused with this status a lot! can someone help me understand, I don't find any good and clear reference online.

Comment: Did you check the man page?

Comment: You marked your post as c++, but c++ does not have waitpid() (i.e. waitpid() is not described in cppreference.com). There is nothing wrong with using the c language. The two languages are not the same.  In non-*nix embedded system os, a C++ compiler is probably available, but there would be no waitpid() anywhere in the system, nor anywhere in your c++ tools.

Comment: @2785528 `waitpid()` is a POSIX function that can be called from either language.

Comment: Agreed, and you have marked your post for Linux.  I guess I'm suggesting you move this post to ask the talented c programmers (of SO) that know more about linux.  .

Comment: @2785528 I'm not the author of the question. The code is C++, since it uses `cout`, not `printf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should work.

1. You're not using the `status` argument, so that doesn't matter.
2. You only have to check `status` if you need to distinguish different ways of the process ending, such as by a signal versus normal exit. For instance you can use `WIFSIGNALED(status)` to tell if it exited due to a signal, and you can use `WEXITSTATUS(status)` to get the value that it passed to `exit()`.

The last comment only matters if you have some other `wait()` or `waitpid()` call that might detect the process exiting. If this is the only one, you should be fine.

If the code is in a loop, put `break` after you print `Hello` to stop checking.

It would be good to check if `return_pid == -1`, which indicates an error, and stop the loop. If somehow the status was received by some other wait call, you'll get an error and this will keep you from retrying forever.

Comment: And WNOHANG won't block, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, why sometimes we MUST check status (like seeing if process is currently stopped or not) other times no need (like this one)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can someone answer me please?

Comment: @lion I already answered that. You check status if you need to know *why* the process exited.

Comment: "You check status if you need to know why the process exited" But here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198771/c-check-for-stopped-process you check the status to determine if process was stopped briefly or not.

Comment: Since you're not using the `WUNTRACED` flag, I didn't think that case was relevant here.